# Ionic 2 connecting/downloading/uploading to a FTP server

Tags: angular, ftp, ionic2

i have a project where i need to connect to FTP server. You need a link to it, a username and a password to connect. I have all that, server is established and has some files on it. My problem is how do i connect to it, and download file which i'll then save to my database, and then later on upload it back. All the files are .xml Any ideas ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is a FTP plugin for Cordova:
https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp

I have not tested it myself, but I can see it has been updated 12 days ago, so it seems to be maintained.

If you want to use it with Ionic 2 you probably want to write an Ionic Native wrapper for the plugin:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md
This is not required but it makes it a bit nicer to work with the plugins.

To solve your problem you probably also need to use the following plugins:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/ - Local SQLite database
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/ - Resolve file paths,
  read files as text, etc.